# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'e.id' in JPQL custom query

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I can try to get count from sub query then that e.id is shown as invalid path. My query complex that's why i am getting stuck into this. How to solved this error anyone have idea about it.

I am using spring boot with jpa repository. Query written into repository with @Query annotation. I have try using UNION but it cannot support in JPA, JPQL query. So what is the solution using JPQL custome query. I have used constructor in query because i want to add 3 type of count in every row. That's why i have taken contructor based query.

1.DTO

```
package com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.responseDTO;

import lombok.*;

@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public @Data
class ManageGroupsDTO {

    private Long group_id;

    private String group_name;

    private Long groupTypeId;

    private String groupTypeName;

    private Long countUpcomingEvents;

    private Long countPastEvents;

    private Long countFollows;

    private String groupStates;
}
```

2.Query

```
@Repository
public interface GroupsDao extends JpaRepository<Groups, Long> {

   @Query("SELECT new com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.responseDTO.ManageGroupsDTO(g.group_id, " +
            "g.group_name, gt.group_type_id, gt.name, COUNT(e.id), COUNT(ee.id), COUNT(mgf.id), gs.name) " +
            "FROM Groups g LEFT JOIN MemberFollowGroups mgf LEFT JOIN mgf.groups gf ON gf.group_id = g.group_id " +
            "JOIN g.groupTypes gt LEFT JOIN g.primary_contact_member_id pm " +
            "LEFT JOIN g.secondary_contact_member_id sm LEFT JOIN g.groupStates gs " +
            "WHERE (pm.member_id=:memberId OR sm.member_id=:memberId) IN " +
            "(SELECT e FROM Events e LEFT JOIN e.eventRecurrence er LEFT JOIN e.groups eg ON eg.group_id = g.group_id WHERE e.startDate >=:todayDate) AND " +
            "(SELECT ee FROM Events ee LEFT JOIN ee.eventRecurrence er LEFT JOIN ee.groups eg ON eg.group_id = g.group_id WHERE ee.startDate <:todayDate) " +
            "GROUP BY g.group_id")
    List<ManageGroupsDTO> manageMyGroupList(LocalDate todayDate, Long memberId);
}
```

3.error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.dao.GroupsDao.manageMyGroupList(java.time.LocalDate,java.lang.Long)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:140) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:207) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:574) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:567) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1051) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:569) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'e.id' [SELECT new com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.responseDTO.ManageGroupsDTO(g.group_id, g.group_name, gt.group_type_id, gt.name, COUNT(e.id), COUNT(ee.id), COUNT(mgf.id), gs.name) FROM com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.model.Groups g LEFT JOIN com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.model.MemberFollowGroups mgf LEFT JOIN mgf.groups gf ON gf.group_id = g.group_id JOIN g.groupTypes gt LEFT JOIN g.primary_contact_member_id pm LEFT JOIN g.secondary_contact_member_id sm LEFT JOIN g.groupStates gs WHERE (pm.member_id=:memberId OR sm.member_id=:memberId) IN (SELECT e FROM com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.model.Events e LEFT JOIN e.eventRecurrence er LEFT JOIN e.groups eg ON eg.group_id = g.group_id WHERE e.startDate >=:todayDate) AND (SELECT ee FROM com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.model.Events ee LEFT JOIN ee.eventRecurrence er LEFT JOIN ee.groups eg ON eg.group_id = g.group_id WHERE ee.startDate <:todayDate) GROUP BY g.group_id]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:718) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:368) ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'e.id' [SELECT new com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.responseDTO.ManageGroupsDTO(g.group_id, g.group_name, gt.group_type_id, gt.name, COUNT(e.id), COUNT(ee.id), COUNT(mgf.id), gs.name) FROM com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.model.Groups g LEFT JOIN com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.model.MemberFollowGroups mgf LEFT JOIN mgf.groups gf ON gf.group_id = g.group_id JOIN g.groupTypes gt LEFT JOIN g.primary_contact_member_id pm LEFT JOIN g.secondary_contact_member_id sm LEFT JOIN g.groupStates gs WHERE (pm.member_id=:memberId OR sm.member_id=:memberId) IN (SELECT e FROM com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.model.Events e LEFT JOIN e.eventRecurrence er LEFT JOIN e.groups eg ON eg.group_id = g.group_id WHERE e.startDate >=:todayDate) AND (SELECT ee FROM com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.model.Events ee LEFT JOIN ee.eventRecurrence er LEFT JOIN ee.groups eg ON eg.group_id = g.group_id WHERE ee.startDate <:todayDate) GROUP BY g.group_id]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:600) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:709) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're misunderstanding query mechanism a bit.

1. There should be no `new` call whatsoever - jpa can assemble entity for you and `select new ...` looks faulty by design to me.
2. `JpaRepository<Groups, Long>` looks wrong if you want to achieve return type of `List<ManageGroupsDTO>` - there should be something like `JpaRepository<ManageGroupsDTO, Long>`
3. `@ToString` annotation for your entity is most likely redudant because of `@Data` annotation which also includes `.toString()` method creation afaik.

Summing up, try something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface GroupsDao extends JpaRepository<ManageGroupsDTO, Long> {

   @Query("SELECT g.group_id, g.group_name, gt.group_type_id, gt.name, COUNT(e.id), COUNT(ee.id), COUNT(mgf.id), gs.name " +
            "FROM Groups g LEFT JOIN MemberFollowGroups mgf LEFT JOIN mgf.groups gf ON gf.group_id = g.group_id " +
            "JOIN g.groupTypes gt LEFT JOIN g.primary_contact_member_id pm " +
            "LEFT JOIN g.secondary_contact_member_id sm LEFT JOIN g.groupStates gs " +
            "WHERE (pm.member_id=:memberId OR sm.member_id=:memberId) IN " +
            "(SELECT e FROM Events e LEFT JOIN e.eventRecurrence er LEFT JOIN e.groups eg ON eg.group_id = g.group_id WHERE e.startDate >=:todayDate) AND " +
            "(SELECT ee FROM Events ee LEFT JOIN ee.eventRecurrence er LEFT JOIN ee.groups eg ON eg.group_id = g.group_id WHERE ee.startDate <:todayDate) " +
            "GROUP BY g.group_id")
    List<ManageGroupsDTO> manageMyGroupList(LocalDate todayDate, Long memberId);
}
```

If you did not messed with result set positioning it should be fixed this way.

Comment: but in JpaRepository<Groups, Long>  in this repo there more query is there. so how can take repo as like JpaRepository<ManageGroupsDTO, Long>

Comment: if i am taking two repo then they will give error like : - Not a managed type: class com.techavidus.networkingPhoniex.responseDTO.ManageGroupsDTO

Comment: `Not a managed type class` sort of error occurs because you forgot to annotate your dto with `@Entity` and corresponding table reference. Try fixing it as well

Comment: i have already entity of this class of Groups. So why i want to create new entity for that. I want 3 field explicitly add into DTO and other field can automatically bind from Entity to DTO.

Comment: I doubt jpa can really work this way. If you have some nested entities you got to use separate repository interfaces for each and `ManageGroupsDTO` should be field of `Groups` entity via `@OneToOne` / `@OneToMany` relationship, so to make `GroupsDao` repo work you most likely should follow steps above.